# Unpacking and testing nested dictionaries values python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to transform a dictionaries of list and nested dictionaries into a cleaner list of dictionaries **but** testing one of the nested values.

Basically from this:

```
my_dict = {
    'N': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 1}, 
        {'DATE': 2018, 'VALUE': 2}
    ], 
    'LT': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 40}, 
        {'DATE': 2001, 'VALUE': 50}
    ]
}
```

to this:

```
my_dict_transformed = [
    {'DATE': 2019, 'N': 1, 'LT': 40}, 
    {'DATE': 2018, 'N': 2, 'LT': 'NULL'}, 
    {'DATE': 2001, 'N': 'NULL', 'LT': 50}
]
```

Thanks to all the solutions proposed. I think @Rakesh solution is the cleanest. While having a default function like @Anurag suggested could be very useful with a slightly different data structure.

Comment: where's your code/logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
my_dict = {
    'N': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 1}, 
        {'DATE': 2018, 'VALUE': 2}
    ], 
    'LT': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 40}, 
        {'DATE': 2001, 'VALUE': 50}
    ]
}

my_dict_transformed = {}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    for i in v:
        if i["DATE"] not in my_dict_transformed:
            my_dict_transformed[i["DATE"]] = {'DATE': i["DATE"]}
            my_dict_transformed[i["DATE"]].update(dict((i,"NULL") for i in my_dict.keys()))
        my_dict_transformed[i["DATE"]][k] = i.pop('VALUE')
print(list(my_dict_transformed.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'DATE': 2001, 'LT': 50},
 {'DATE': 2018, 'N': 2},
 {'DATE': 2019, 'LT': 40, 'N': 1}]
```

Comment: clean solution. The only thing is that 'LT' is not added (e.g. 'LT': 'NULL') when the keys are not equals.

Comment: Are they constant? `LT` & `N`

Comment: variables actually, but always numbers (reals)

Answer (score 2):

With old-good `collections.defaultdict` object:

```
from collections import defaultdict

parent_keys = my_dict.keys()
d = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    for date in v:
        val = date.pop('VALUE')
        d[date['DATE']].update(dict({k: val}, **date))
        diff = parent_keys - d[date['DATE']].keys()
        if diff:
            d[date['DATE']].update({diff_k: 'NULL' for diff_k in diff})

print(list(d.values()))
```

The output:

```
[{'N': 1, 'DATE': 2019, 'LT': 40}, {'N': 2, 'DATE': 2018, 'LT': 'NULL'}, {'LT': 50, 'DATE': 2001, 'N': 'NULL'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
my_dict = {
    'N': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 1},
        {'DATE': 2018, 'VALUE': 2}
    ],
    'LT': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 40},
        {'DATE': 2001, 'VALUE': 50}
    ]
}

from itertools import groupby

null_d = list({k: 'NULL' for k in my_dict}.items())
s = sorted(((k, i) for k, v in my_dict.items() for i in v), key=lambda k: k[1]['DATE'])
data = [dict([('DATE',v)] + null_d + [(v[0], v[1]['VALUE']) for v in g] ) for v, g in groupby(s, key=lambda k: k[1]['DATE'])]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
[{'DATE': 2001, 'LT': 50, 'N': 'NULL'},
 {'DATE': 2018, 'LT': 'NULL', 'N': 2},
 {'DATE': 2019, 'LT': 40, 'N': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict = {
    'N': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 1}, 
        {'DATE': 2018, 'VALUE': 2}
    ], 
    'LT': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 40}, 
        {'DATE': 2001, 'VALUE': 50}
    ]
}



res =[]

for i in my_dict['N']:
    dic = [i['DATE'],i['VALUE'],'NULL']
    res.append(dic)

for i in my_dict['LT']:
    flag = 0
    for j in res:
        if i['DATE'] == j[0] and flag ==0:
            flag = 1
            j[2]=i['VALUE']

    if flag==0:
        dic = [i['DATE'],'NULL',i['VALUE']]
        res.append(dic)
    flag = 0

sol = [{'DATE':i[0], 'N':i[1],'LT':i[2]} for i in res ]

print(sol)
```

output

```
[{'DATE': 2019, 'N': 1, 'LT': 40}, {'DATE': 2018, 'N': 2, 'LT': 'NULL'}, {'DATE': 2001, 'N': 'NULL', 'LT': 50}]
```

Answer (score 1):

hi this code works for me

```
my_dict = {
    'N': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 1}, 
        {'DATE': 2018, 'VALUE': 2}
    ], 
    'LT': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 40}, 
        {'DATE': 2001, 'VALUE': 50}
    ]
}

datas = []

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    for item in v:
        for key in my_dict.keys():
            item[key] = None
        item[k] = item['VALUE']
        del item['VALUE']
        datas.append(item)

out = []
years = []
for i in range(len(datas)):
    if datas[i]["DATE"] not in years:
        list_out_date = list(filter(lambda x: x['DATE'] == datas[i]["DATE"], datas))
        temp_date = list_out_date[0]
        for date in list_out_date:
            for k, v in temp_date.items():
                if temp_date[k] == None and date[k] != None:
                    temp_date[k] = date[k]
        out.append(temp_date)
        years.append(datas[i]["DATE"])

print(out)
```

output:

```
[{'DATE': 2019, 'N': 1, 'LT': 40}, {'DATE': 2018, 'N': 2, 'LT': None}, {'DATE': 2001, 'N': None, 'LT': 50}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution. It's a little bigger than the other solutions given here. But it will work for any number of lists in your dictionary.

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import groupby
from operator import add, itemgetter


def merge_list_of_records_by(key, combine):
    """Returns a function that merges a list of records, grouped by
       the specified key, with values combined using the specified
       binary operator."""
    keyprop = itemgetter(key)
    return lambda lst: [
        reduce(merge_records_by(key, combine), records)
        for _, records in groupby(sorted(lst, key=keyprop), keyprop)
    ]

my_dict = {
    'N': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 1}, 
        {'DATE': 2018, 'VALUE': 2}
    ], 
    'LT': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 40}, 
        {'DATE': 2001, 'VALUE': 50}
    ]
}

keys= [k for k,v in my_dict.items()]
new_list =[]
final =[]

for k,v in my_dict.items():
    for i in v:
        for m in keys:
            i[m] = 0
        i[k] = i['VALUE']
        del i['VALUE']

    new_list.append(v)        

merger = merge_list_of_records_by('DATE', add)

for k in new_list:
    final = merger(final + k)

print('Final:', final)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'N': 0, 'LT': 50, 'DATE': 2001}, {'N': 2, 'LT': 0, 'DATE': 2018}, {'N': 1, 'LT': 40, 'DATE': 2019}]
```

Comment: working fine, a little typo in `final = merger(final + k` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
#python 3.5.2

from pprint import pprint

my_dict = {
    'N': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 1}, 
        {'DATE': 2018, 'VALUE': 2}
    ], 
    'LT': [
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 40}, 
        {'DATE': 2001, 'VALUE': 50}
    ],
    'GT': [
        {'DATE': 2020, 'VALUE': 170}, 
    ],
    'EQ': [
        {'DATE': 2020, 'VALUE': 170}, 
        {'DATE': 2019, 'VALUE': 42}
    ],
}

kk = {k: None for k in my_dict}
pivot = {}
for k in kk:
    for t in my_dict[k]:
        d = t['DATE']
        pivot[d] = pivot.get(d, {**{'DATE': d}, **kk,})
        pivot[d][k] = t['VALUE']
pprint(list(pivot.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'DATE': 2001, 'EQ': None, 'GT': None, 'LT': 50, 'N': None},
 {'DATE': 2018, 'EQ': None, 'GT': None, 'LT': None, 'N': 2},
 {'DATE': 2019, 'EQ': 42, 'GT': None, 'LT': 40, 'N': 1},
 {'DATE': 2020, 'EQ': 170, 'GT': 170, 'LT': None, 'N': None}]
```

Test it online with [rextester.com](https://rextester.com/NPIL97026).